# cardinality of $V_\omega$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm unfamiliar with set theory so bear with me.

Let $V_\alpha$ be the members of the von Neumann Hierarchy, so $$V_0 = \{ \}, V_{\alpha + 1 } = \mathcal{P} (V_\alpha), V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha$$. (Note that $\mathcal{P} (S)$ denotes the power set of $S$.) In particular, $V_\omega = \bigcup_{n < \omega} V_n$. I claim that $|V_\omega| = \aleph_0$. My idea is that essentially, each $V_n$ has finitely many elements, so we can list all the elements of all the $V_n$ in a countable list. Then removing duplicates gives us the elements of $V_\omega$, so $|V_\omega| = \aleph_0$.

Is the above argument valid (especially the "listing the elements" part)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, albeit pretty informal. Here are three ways to formally prove that $V_\omega$ is countable.

Proof 1. Fix, for each $1 \le n < \omega$, $k_n < \omega$ and a bijection $f_n \colon k_n \to V_n \setminus V_{n-1}$. This is possible, since each $V_n$ is finite. Now let $k_0 := 0$ and
$$
f \colon \omega \to V_{\omega}, x \mapsto f_n(x- \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k_i),
$$
where $n$ is maximal such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}k_i \le x$. This is a bijection.

Proof 2. Since $V_n$ is finite for each $n < \omega$, $V_\omega = \bigcup_{n < \omega} V_n$ is a countable union of countable (in fact finite) sets. Using the general result that countable unions of countable sets are countable, it follows that $V_\omega$ is countable.

Proof 3. Recursively define a function (known as [Ackermann's coding function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set))
$$
f \colon \omega \to V_\omega
$$
with the following property: If $(n_i, \ldots, n_k)$ is the *binary coding of $n$* - by which I mean that $n_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $n = \sum_{i=0}^k n_i 2^i$ - then 
$$
f(n) := \{ f(i) \mid n_i = 1 \}.
$$
It's a nice exercise to prove that $f$ is well-defined and in fact a bijection.

Comment: Note that the current phrasing of Proof 2 makes it depend on $AC$.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Well, no. It uses a fact that in general is only provable with some form of choice (and so does proof 1), but in this case it is provable outright - without any choice. But yes, I am aware that my phrasing suggests a need for choice and I contemplated to address this. Ultimately I decided not to, mostly because OP isn't very accustomed to set theory.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf To be more precise about the part 'in this case it is provable outright - without any choice': I'm thinking of something like $\operatorname{ZF}$ proves 'If for each $n < \omega$ there is a bijection $f_n \colon \omega \to A_n$ and the sequence $(f_n \mid n < \omega)$ exists, then there is a bijection $f \colon \omega \to \bigcup_{n < \omega} A_n$'.

Comment: Nice proofs. A minor suggestion: In Proof 3, you could change the notation $n^i$ to $n_i$ -- your current notation is confusing because you're also using $2^i$ to refer to exponentiation.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Does AC mean Axiom of Choice? Why are ``small-scale'' statements provable without Axiom of Choice?

@Stefan Is it accurate to say that the Ackermann's coding function works on the same principle as the von Neumann universe (namely, iterating power sets)? Can I use this to prove that f is surjective?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it does. There is a subtle point, as Stefan observed in his comment. The statement _“if $A_n$ are countable then $\bigcup_n A_n$ is”_ requires $AC$ because you have to *choose*, for each $n$, a bijection witnessing that $A_n$ is countable. But this is not the case if $A_n$ are some explicit sets and for each $n$ there is a explicit injection from $A_n$ into $\omega$. Hope this helps. Also, I'm not certain of what you mean by "small scale".

Comment: @Anonymous Well, the Ackermann coding function and the cumulative hierarchy (the $V_\alpha$) do - in some sense - work on the same principle, namely both are constructed recursively. Other than that, they don't have much in common.

Comment: @Anonymous To prove that $f$ is surjective, use an $\in$-induction on $x \in V_{\omega}$.

Answer (score 2):

In ZF it is not a theorem that every countable union of finite sets is countable.

Another way to show that $|V_{\omega}|=\omega$ :

$V_0=\phi$ has a (unique, empty ) well-order $<_0.$ For $n\in \omega,$ suppose $<_n$ is a well-order on $V_n.$ Define $<_{n+1}$ on $V_{n+1}$ as follows:

(i). If $x,y\in V_n$ then $x<_{n+1}y\iff x<_ny.$

(ii). If $x\in V_n$ and $y\in V_{n+1}$ \ $V_n$ then $x<_{n+1}y.$

(iii). If $x, y\in V_{n+1}$ \ $V_n$ with $x\ne y,$ let $z$ be the $<_n$-least member of $(x$ \ $y)\cup (y$ \ $x).$ Let $x<_{n+1}y\iff z\in y.$

For $x,y\in V_{\omega}$ let $n$ be the least (or any) $m\in \omega$ such that $\{x,y\}\subset V_m.$ Define  $x<_{\omega}y\iff x<_ny.$ Then $<_{\omega}$ is a well-order on $V_{\omega}.$

For $y\in V_{\omega},$ let $y\in V_n$ with $n\in \omega.$  Then pred$_{<_{\omega}}y= \{x:x<_{\omega}y\}\subset V_n,$ which is finite.  A well-order in which every initial segment is finite is order-isomorphic to $\omega$ or to  a member of $\omega.$

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but I think I have an even easier solution:
Note that for all $n\in \omega$, $V_n$ is finite, so we may construct a bijection $f_n: V_n \rightarrow \{0,\dots,|V_n|\}$, a numbering of the elements of $V_n$. Then define an injection $g:V_\omega \rightarrow \omega^2$ by $g(a) = (\text{rank}(a), f_{\text{rank}(a)}(a))$. Since $|\omega^2| = |\omega|$, we have shown $|V_\omega| \leq \aleph_0$. It's trivial to construct an injection from $\omega \rightarrow V_\omega$ (take the identity mapping), so by Schroder-Bernstein, $|V_\omega| = \aleph_0$.

Comment: Yes, but why does the argument work in ZF?